# NOT IN Operation on multilple value (Sybase SQL)

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I am trying to write a SQL like:

```
SELECT * 
   FROM TABLE1 
   WHERE (TABLE1.A, TABLE1.B) NOT IN 
   (SELECT TABLE2.A, TABLE2.B FROM TABLE2)
```

It seems this is not allowed in Sybase.

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

IN and NOT IN indeed work only on a single column. 
The solution is not so difficult: concatenate the columns into a single value. For example, if both are VARCHAR columns, do something like this:

```
WHERE (TABLE1.A||'~~~'||TABLE1.B) NOT IN 
      (SELECT TABLE2.A||'~~~'||TABLE2.B FROM TABLE2)
```

This assumes that the string '~~~' will not occur in the data -- pick any string that works for you.